# Examine whether the sequences are bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

> 1) $(x_n) = \frac 1n$
>
> 2) $(y_n) = 3n^2 +2$

In the first question the lower bound is $0$ and the upper bound is $1$.
In the second question the lower bound is 5 and there is no upper bound.
Why is the lower bound different in both sums?

Comment: What sums? I don't see any sums. Also, what values of $n$ are allowed?

Comment: n belongs to natural numbers. So first sum I get { 1,1/2,1/3,1/4....}  And the second sum I get { 5,14,29,50....}

Comment: Sums have plus signs. $\{\,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots\,\}$ has no plus signs, so it's not a sum. Also, do you count zero as a natural number?

Comment: No 0 is not a natural number. But the book I'm referring has put 0 as lower bound.

Comment: The inputs have to be natural numbers, so in particular not zero, but the lower bound has to do with the output, and there's no reason to expect that to be a natural number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sequence 1) is different from 2), I do not understand your question I think.

**EDIT**

$0$ can't be the lower bound of 2) because we know that $3>0$ and $2>0$ and $n^2\geq1, \forall n$. Therefore $3n^2\geq3, \forall n$ and therefore $3n^2+2\geq 5>0, \forall n$.

Comment: Why can't 0 be the lower bound in question 2? They have taken 0 as lower bound and 1 as upper bound in question one. While in question 2, 5 is taken as lower bound and it is said that no maximum bound can be determined in the second question.

Comment: Okay I get it now. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Okay a doubt..  In the first question why can't there be no lower bound and just an upper bound which is 1

Comment: 1 is the upper bound of 1)! $\frac{1}{n}$ is a decreasing function, so the largest value is obtained when you choose $n$ the smallest (=1), therefore the upper bound is equal to 1.

Comment: Ohhh gotcha. Thanks a lot!!!